# Cannot import anything from bit.dev to my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, bit.dev

I have a React project; I am trying to import a component from bit.dev, but it does not work for some reason.

I have installed the package on my terminal using:

```
bit import nexxtway.react-rainbow/button
```

link: https://bit.dev/nexxtway/react-rainbow/button

It added to my package.json files in dependencies key as well:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@bit/nexxtway.react-rainbow.button": "file:./components/button"
}
```

and I am trying to use it on my App.js file as:

```
import { Button } from '@bit/nexxtway.react-rainbow.button';

class App extends Component {
   render() {
      <Button
         label="Button Brand"
         onClick={() => alert('clicked!')}
         variant="brand" 
      />
   }
```

It either gives me an error or nothing it appears as an empty `<div>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs you have imported the button incorrectly -

change

```
import { Button } from '@bit/nexxtway.react-rainbow.button';
```

to

```
import Button from '@bit/nexxtway.react-rainbow.button';
```

Comment: since your component is exported as default: `export default class Button extends Component {`, it should be imported with no curlies.